# gama wheel menu bar - how to add click events to icons in Android

Tags: android

**edit:** I asked this question again.. Because I can not take true answer on this question so you can look for full answer

[Answer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435794/wheel-menu-bar-how-can-i-give-click-action-to-icons/22449916?noredirect=1#22449916)

And I try to this icon clickable but I can not do . How can I makte this icons clickevent do you know any way.

and these icons are not in xml. They are on draw able folder.
this is gives methods can we use it [methods about gama wheel library](http://developer.digitalaria.com/reference/en/gama/android/)

And this is my trying

```
package com.myproject.gama;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel;
import com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.WheelAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.util.Log;

public class SampleWheelActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = SampleWheelActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Wheel wheel;
    public WheelAdapter<Adapter> adapter;
    private Resources res; 
    public int[] icons = { 
         R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon0 , R.drawable.icon2};
    ImageView t;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        wheel = (Wheel) findViewById(R.id.wheel);       
        wheel.setItems(getDrawableFromData(icons));
        wheel.setWheelDiameter(400);


    }
    /*I am delete it 
    @Override
    public void onResume(){

        //first try
        ImageView iconsa[] = new ImageView[icons[0]];
        ImageView iconsa1[] = new ImageView[icons[1]];
        ImageView iconsa2[] = new ImageView[icons[1]];

        //second try
        String arrayStr = Arrays.toString (icons);
        String[] aa = arrayStr.split(",");
        String[] strArray = new String[] {arrayStr};
        for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++)
        {
            iconsa[i] = new ImageView(wheel.getContext());
             iconsa[i].setOnClickListener(onClick());

        }
    }
   */ 

// I am delete it too

/*  private OnClickListener onClick() {
         Toast.makeText(SampleWheelActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//   how can ı Reach id on drawable folder icons
        return null;
    } */



    private Drawable[] getDrawableFromData(int[] data) {
        Drawable[] ret = new Drawable[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ret[i] = res.getDrawable(data[i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }

//I try it but how can I give clickevent icon1.. when click icon1 it should go other page

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong listener. You need to use `WheelAdapter.OnItemSelectionUpdatedListener` from this [Reference](http://developer.digitalaria.com/reference/en/gama/android/).

Here is my working code for same.

```
public class SampleWheelActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener 
{
    private Wheel wheel;
    private Resources res; 
    private int[] icons = 
        { 
            R.drawable.icon00, R.drawable.icon01, R.drawable.icon02, 
            R.drawable.icon03, R.drawable.icon04, R.drawable.icon05, 
            R.drawable.icon06, R.drawable.icon07, R.drawable.icon08, 
            R.drawable.icon09, R.drawable.icon10, R.drawable.icon11 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        init();
    }

    private void init() 
    {
        res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        wheel = (Wheel) findViewById(R.id.wheel);

        wheel.setItems(getDrawableFromData(icons));
        wheel.setWheelDiameter(800);
        wheel.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private Drawable[] getDrawableFromData(int[] data) 
    {
        Drawable[] ret = new Drawable[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ret[i] = res.getDrawable(data[i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }


    // This method will get fire when you click on any image.    
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(WheelAdapter<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        System.out.println ( "id :" + id ); 
    }
}
```

I am successfully able to get result when clicking on any image with the help of onItemClick().

Comment: But what can ı use for reach id. İgamebutton or image drawable do not have click event

Comment: Could you give me example one click action on icon.  Becuse ı try it before but ı can not reach id in this method

Comment: And it gives   wheel.setOnItemClickListener((com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.WheelAdapter.OnItemClickListener) this);

Comment: The method setOnItemClickListener(WheelAdapter.OnItemClickListener) in the type Wheel is not applicable for the arguments (SampleWheelActivity)

Comment: do you give me your imports

Comment: @19052013, I have give you code, whats the problem ?

Comment: Beforw ı used this method but I can not give click item.. for example could you give me code how can I give clickeven icon1 ?? I try it so Much but ı can not.. :((

Comment: But mine code is working fine. did you check the logs ?

Comment: Yes but you said syso id but I do not understand how can I give click action with R, id,? What and could you give me example on code only icon1 click evet.. sory my bad English the end I can not give click event icon1 in onItemclick method. I do not idea

Comment: May be you can try this `icons[0]` instead of id of first image.

Comment: I do not have any idea how can I give clickevent id.. :(( I try icon[0].id but could you show me how it ? How can I give click event icon0 could you write code dude

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49483/discussion-between-19052013-and-user2060383)