# wheel menu bar how can I give click action to icons

Tags: android, android-wheel

Before I asked this question. They said add method. I added but how can I give click event icon0. It is problem for me still..

[first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243655/gama-wheel-menu-bar-how-to-add-click-events-to-icons-in-android)

and these icons are not in xml. They are on draw able folder.
this is gives methods can we use it

And this is my trying

```
package com.myproject.gama;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel;
import com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.WheelAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.util.Log;

public class SampleWheelActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = SampleWheelActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Wheel wheel;
    public WheelAdapter<Adapter> adapter;
    private Resources res; 
    public int[] icons = { 
         R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon0 , R.drawable.icon2};
    ImageView t;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        init();
      //first example:I try onitemclickListenner but I could not work again click event on icon1

       /*   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.main ,icons[1] ));

       ListView listView = getListView();
       listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {               
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hahhaa",            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
    }
});
*/
    }

    private void init() {
        res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        wheel = (Wheel) findViewById(R.id.wheel);       
        wheel.setItems(getDrawableFromData(icons));
        wheel.setWheelDiameter(400);
         //I try this new
              wheel.setOnItemClickListener(new WheelAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(WheelAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
         //how can I reach icon1 ?
             //I try it according to Ȃŵåiṩ ĸîŋg answer but still I can not reach icon1
         String selected;

             selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(icons.length + position).toString();
                if( selected.equals("icon0") ){
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+"icon0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else if( selected.equals("icon1")){
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+"icon1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else if(  selected.equals("icon2")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+"icon2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


        }});



    }



    private Drawable[] getDrawableFromData(int[] data) {
        Drawable[] ret = new Drawable[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ret[i] = res.getDrawable(data[i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }

//I try it but how can I give clickevent icon1.. when click icon1 it should go other page. 

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1);

            //how can I do when I click this icon1 , it is go other page ???
            // how can do give click action
            // how should I fill this method



}

}
```

**And this is my xml file there is no id icons on xml. They are at draw able folder..**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/cell_bg"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, GAMA!" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/belirtec9_2bg"
        android:paddingTop="10px"
    >

    <com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel
        android:id="@+id/wheel"
        android:paddingTop="10px" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried using setOnItemClickListener? [the documentation](http://developer.digitalaria.com/reference/en/gama/android/com/digitalaria/gama/wheel/Wheel.html#setOnItemClickListener(com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.WheelAdapter.OnItemClickListener)) specifies that.

Comment: yes but May be I used it wrong.. :(( my english is bad. So sometimes I understand wrong this document.. I should see example. How it is used

Comment: @gkapagunta I put my try about onItemclick on question

Comment: use wheel.setOnItemClickListener(new WheelAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){});

Comment: @gkapagunta Yes, I try it but still I do not any idea how can  I give click event icon1.. it is not image on xml file.. it is on only drawable folder. I updated my question again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
wheel.setOnItemClickListener(new WheelAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(WheelAdapter<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Here I am using other activities to be opened on item press,
        // you can use any other action which you like.
        if (position == 0) {
            // First icon is pressed
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyNewClass.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            // Second icon is pressed
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MySecondClass.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: When I click all icons it gives same action.very thanks but How can do this only icon1, icon0... because they are action different :(( Do you give me example on code only icon1. please

Comment: I try to it I update my question but still I can not reach icon1

Comment: yess it is work very good thanks dude.. :))) and I am new at this form.. How can I do when this icons comes top of page, it should clickable.. Should I asked other question.. or May you help me ^.^

Comment: sure! I'll try to help you get rid of your problem. :)

Comment: So much thanks. :)) as you see if you import this project when you click icon it is go top of circle.  how can I do  icons should clickable when it is only top of circle

Comment: like touching buttons in layout, when circle is on?

Comment: yess =)) like this. When icons top of circle it should click able http://www.code4app.com/photo/508e00cd6803fad324000000_1.png some like this for example icons are top of an it is click able.

Comment: you mean, change icon on press?
white to red or any other color

Comment: you'll need selector drawable and 2 drawable icons (1=normal state; 2=pressed state)

Answer (score 1):

This code only adds circle on item:

```
    wheel.setOnItemClickListener(new WheelAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(WheelAdapter<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ImageView v = (ImageView) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Drawable pd = (Drawable) v.getDrawable();
            Paint paint = new Paint(); paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            //TODO: Set Color and width of circle
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

            Bitmap mutableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)pd).getBitmap()).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
            canvas.drawCircle(((BitmapDrawable)pd).getBitmap().getWidth()/2, ((BitmapDrawable)pd).getBitmap().getHeight()/2, 30, paint);
            v.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So sory my bad english I want to said like this  http://imageshack.com/a/img21/8687/w3f1.jpg when icon comes in this circle they should be click able only click in pink circle

Comment: I try do something and ı put a code.  Keep take out

Comment: Anytime bro, :)
you can add me on FB or contact me on WhatsApp for help.
fb.com/Awais.is.King
+92 3063355690